# How to fix CollectionView SelectionMode="Single" Error when users accidently click multiple items at the same time in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm using SelectionMode="Single" in my CollectionView of Xamarin.Forms, but whenever users accidently click or tap on multiple items at the same time, it will crash my app.
I tried using try{}catch{} around SelectionChangedCommand & SelectedItem, but it still does not help. The error that I can find in Visual Studio after the app crash is "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'" How do I fix this?

```
  #MyCollectionViewCode:

  <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Content}" ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView"
  SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData}"                            
  SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding DoDisplay}" 
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplateSelector}"                     
  />
```

Comment: Can you provide code and steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: what does the stack trace show as the initial line causing the exception?

Comment: @Sir Mayer, how my code works is whenever a user click on an item in the CollectionView, a DisplayAlert() function will execute to display data from the selected item. wait i am trying to find the best way to show you the entire code.

Comment: @Sir Jason. the Call stack or stack trace shows nothing beside "[External Code]" following with blank board.

Comment: You know what I think even with multi selection mode on, this issue won't go because I'm pretty sure you have a piece of code in your code that causing this not the collection view itself

Comment: Mysterious "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" involving a "bound" list that is shown in UI often indicates that you are accessing that list from a thread other than the background thread. This does not cause a thread exception, because the "bound" list (`Content`) is not itself a UI Element. HOWEVER, if you ADD OR DELETE ITEMS from `Content` on a different thread, and the UI simultaneously tries to display UI, the list length might change "out from underneath" the UI. Hence the exception you see. For further help, please show all code that accesses `Content`.

Comment: dear +everyone i just want to let you know that i have fixed this issue already. It was ObservableCollection Content.Clear() that caused this error.

Comment: Appreciated everyone's advice !